# how to show my admin tab in prestashop 1.7?

Tags: prestashop

i succeeded to show my admin tab in ps 1.6 bu it does not appear in 1.7, here is my code :

```
  public function installTab()  {
    $tab = new Tab();
    $tab->id_parent = 0;
    //$tab->id_parent = (int)Tab::getIdFromClassName('AdminCatalog');
    $tab->name = array();
    foreach (Language::getLanguages(true) as $lang) {
        $tab->name[$lang['id_lang']] = 'Scan des codes barre';
      }
    $tab->class_name = 'AdminBarCodeGenerator';
    $tab->module = $this->name;
    $tab->active = 1;
    return $tab->add();
```

}

and my controller's methods:

```
 public function __construct(){
    $this->bootstrap = true;
    $this->display='';
    $this->context = Context::getContext();
    return parent::__construct();

}

   public function renderList()
```

{

```
$scan_form=$this->renderForm2();
$this->context->smarty->assign('scan_form',$scan_form);
return $this->context->smarty->fetch(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.'barcode/views/templates/admin/tabs/scan.tpl');
```

}

is there a specific way to handle it in ps 1.7 please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem might be in setting parent id to 0. Try:

```
$tab->id_parent = (int)Tab::getIdFromClassName('DEFAULT');
```

Also your class name should start with `Admin`

Comment: i tried your solution with the parameter `$tab->position = 99` as i saw in a tutorial and it worked both ps 1.6 and 1.7

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand it correctly. So it solves your problem, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you have to do it;

```
public function installTab()
{
    $tab = new Tab();
    $tab->active = 1;
    $tab->class_name = "NewsletterBuildingConfig";
    $tab->name = array();
    foreach (Language::getLanguages(true) as $lang) {
        $tab->name[$lang['id_lang']] = "Newsletter Settings";
    }
    $tab->id_parent = (int)Tab::getIdFromClassName('AdminParentThemes');
    $tab->module = $this->name;
    $tab->add();

    return true;
}
```

Make sure to install your tab in the install() function

```
$this->installTab('AdminParentThemes', 'NewsletterBuildingConfig', 'Newsletter Settings')
```

And then for your admin controller **NewsletterBuildingConfig.php**

```
class NewsletterBuildingConfigController extends ModuleAdminController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        parent::__construct();
        // Redirect is not needed, you can display your tpl file here
        Tools::redirect(
        $this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminModules', true).'&configure=newsletterbuilderandsender'
        );
}
```

}

Comment: i put the `installtab` method inside the install medthod otherwise the tab would not appear in the prestashop 1.6 version and the difference between the both codes is the `redirection` you inserted in the construct method, which i inserted but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

It's easy in new versions.

In main php file of your module(yourmodule.php):

```
public $tabs = [
    [
        'name' => 'Merchant Expertise', // One name for all langs
        'class_name' => 'AdminGamification',
        'visible' => true,
        'parent_class_name' => 'ShopParameters',
    ],
];
```

name can be an array for languages:

```
[
    'en' => 'Some text',
    'fa' => 'متن تست'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If do you want to show the tabs event 1.6 and 1.7, use this structure :

For 1.7:

```
 class mymodule extends Module
{
    public $tabs = array(
        array(
            'name' => 'My Tab Name',
            'class_name' => 'AdminMyModuleNameControllerName',
            'visible' => true,
            'parent_class_name' => 'AdminParentModulesSf',
        ),
    );
....
```

and for 1.6:

```
    public function install()
    { ...

     if(!version_compare(_PS_VERSION_, '1.7', '>=')){
        foreach ($this->tabs as $tabItem) {
                            $tab = new Tab();
                            $tab->name = array();
                            foreach (Language::getLanguages(true) as $lang) {
                                $tab->name[$lang['id_lang']] = $tabItem['name'];
              
                  }
                        $tab->class_name = $tabItem['class_name'];
                        $tab->id_parent = Tab::getIdFromClassName($tabItem['parent_class_name']);
                        $tab->module = $this->name;
                        $tab->position = 0;
                        $tab->active = $tabItem['visible'] ? 1 : 0;
                        $tab->save();
                    }
    }
    ...
}
```